# Package created with Rcpp.package.skeleton does not install (g++: error: : No such file or directory)

Tags: r, rcpp

Running Ubuntu 12.04 with R 12.15.2 and Rcpp 0.10.1
gcc version 4.6.3

I have created a skeleton package by:

```
    Rcpp.package.skeleton( "mypackage" )
```

Then running `R CMD INSTALL mypackage` gives the error message:

```
   g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/Rlocal/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
   g++ -shared -o mypackage.so rcpp_hello_world.o  -L/usr/Rlocal/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/Rlocal/Rcpp/lib -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
   g++: error: : No such file or directory
   make: *** [mypackage.so] Error 1
```

Changing to the mypackage/src directory and manually running the g++ commands from above works and does not produce an error.  I can then successfully install the package with R CMD INSTALL (but any changes to source that cause recompilation result in the same error occurring again).

Comment: Non-reproducible question. I develop with the same platform so have a strong case that it usually works, plus our regression tests actually do this, and hence so does CRAN etc pp.  Maybe your `$PATH` gets corrupted?

Comment: Very weird. The third line seems to be not finding something with a blank name (normally it would say "error: woo.c: No such file or directory")